# Inconsistency in boost multiprecision library with modulus

Tags: c++, boost, biginteger

I'm seeing some inconcistency with the boost multiprecision library, using cpp_int and was wondering if the problem is on my end?  Am I doing something wrong?

```
boost::multiprecision::cpp_int value("845812507058753702096720396260955981034309941487979439207575316627396775257009179367680598562088782400182102510047921049667535737841056751035898984440045398065941794853342721440022891483618946596390530332584847468817849746783423105644934675762519035784877729169739110084935079201004991911753548016158266946593610497793934212345180527788034865286995713462176706647193473406223095268503330593499438446017000593156395272905592017851490768402042283892535127698736772114426168690580061412400354553387531076676433901465842118416610671452446364936252601684680593015917270112975907856081311621268680168563153055479531193987696015767888543608430149655940111761214342848772129089336344636193634262254610730");
boost::multiprecision::cpp_int residueResult = value % 733;
std::cout << residueResult;                      // this prints out 4
int residue1 = residueResult.convert_to<int>();  // this is 4
int residue2 = int(value % 733);                 // this is 1
```

Why is it that when doing int(value %733) it gives a value of 1?

This is with boost 1.59.0 and visual studio 2013 community.

Comment: This does not even compile for me. (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faf9afae1a36e126) Please post a [mcve] or tell us what compiler you are using.

Comment: Vs 2013 community edition. What compile error are you getting?

Comment: For errors click the link or read the answer.

Comment: Tip for the future: Don't use C-style casts, I would guess a `static_cast` would not have compiled with MSVC either.

Comment: It does sadly. Tried that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem at hand is that `value % 733` is some implementation-detail proxy type, and you cannot just convert that to `int`. Indeed, that does not even compile with gcc and clang, and as you saw, it yields nonsense with MSVC. To get around that, convert back to `cpp_int` before you cast:

```
int main () {
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_int value("845812507058753702096720396260955981034309941487979439207575316627396775257009179367680598562088782400182102510047921049667535737841056751035898984440045398065941794853342721440022891483618946596390530332584847468817849746783423105644934675762519035784877729169739110084935079201004991911753548016158266946593610497793934212345180527788034865286995713462176706647193473406223095268503330593499438446017000593156395272905592017851490768402042283892535127698736772114426168690580061412400354553387531076676433901465842118416610671452446364936252601684680593015917270112975907856081311621268680168563153055479531193987696015767888543608430149655940111761214342848772129089336344636193634262254610730");
    boost::multiprecision::cpp_int residueResult = value % 733;
    std::cout << residueResult << "\n";                      // this prints out 4
    int residue1 = residueResult.convert_to<int>();  // this is 4
    int residue2 = static_cast<int>(boost::multiprecision::cpp_int(value % 733));                

    std::cout << residue1 << "\n" << residue2;
}
```

This will print

```
4
4
4
```

as desired.

Comment: I think indeed MSVC interprets that `int(expr)` as a C-style cast, which ends up being a `reinterpret_cast<>` there. Sadly the OP only clarified his real question after accepting this one, it seems.

Comment: @sehe According to his comment, `static_cast` does this too on MSVC.

Comment: Seems that MSVC is hitting the conversion to _Bool (safe-bool-idiom) from the `expression` intermediate. That should not happen, but it explains the value `1`

Answer (score 1):

That second cast is invalid and should not compile.

#### GCC

```
test.cpp|9 col 35| error: invalid cast from type ‘boost::enable_if_c<true, boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<boost::multiprecision::detail::modulus_immediates, boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<> >, int, void, void> >::type {aka boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<boost::multiprecision::detail::modulus_immediates, boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<> >, int, void, void>}’ to type ‘int’
||      int residue2 = int(value % 733);                 // this is 1
```

#### clang

```
test.cpp|9 col 20| error: cannot convert 'typename enable_if_c<is_compatible_arithmetic_type<int, number<cpp_int_backend<0, 0, boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type::unchecked, allocator<unsigned long long> >, et_on> >::value && (number_category<cpp_int_backend<0, 0, boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type::unchecked, allocator<unsigned long long> > >::value == number_kind_integer), detail::expression<detail::modulus_immediates, number<cpp_int_backend<0, 0, boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_check_type::unchecked, allocator<unsigned long long> >, et_on>, int> >::type' (aka 'boost::multiprecision::detail::expression<boost::multiprecision::detail::modulus_immediates, boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<0, 0, boost::multiprecision::cpp_integer_type::signed_magnitude, boost::multiprecision::cpp_
|| nt_check_type::unchecked, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long long> >, boost::multiprecision::expression_template_option::et_on>, int, void, void>') to 'int' without a conversion operator
||     int residue2 = int(value % 733);                 // this is 1
||                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

#### Conjecture

If you actually have written this differently then maybe you have gotten a reinterpret_cast, so the result is implementation defined.

#### UPDATE

To the comment:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a889061699fc0ca)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    using Int = boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::cpp_int_backend<>, boost::multiprecision::et_off>;
    Int value("845812507058753702096720396260955981034309941487979439207575316627396775257009179367680598562088782400182102510047921049667535737841056751035898984440045398065941794853342721440022891483618946596390530332584847468817849746783423105644934675762519035784877729169739110084935079201004991911753548016158266946593610497793934212345180527788034865286995713462176706647193473406223095268503330593499438446017000593156395272905592017851490768402042283892535127698736772114426168690580061412400354553387531076676433901465842118416610671452446364936252601684680593015917270112975907856081311621268680168563153055479531193987696015767888543608430149655940111761214342848772129089336344636193634262254610730");

    printf("residue %d:\n", int(value % 733));
}
```

Prints

```
residue 4:
```

Comment: No, I've written it exactly as shown! Do you know the correct way to get an int result without an explicit temporary storage variable? Having residueResult go away so that I have a single line to get the modulus result is what I'm trying to do :/

Comment: Ah: `Int(value % 733).convert_to<int>()`. You can also disable  expression templates: see **[updated answer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a889061699fc0ca)**